# how to allow empty variables in mod rewrite

Tags: php, variables, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/?$ search.php?search=$1 [NC,L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Which works fine if search is defined.

Sometimes the search variable can be left empty or '' to search a whole category.

How does this work with mod rewrite?

When search is defined it would be:

```
search/search-variable/category-name
```

If search is left blank or '' would mod rewrite show it as something like this?

```
search//category-name
```

or skip the variable all together like this:

```
search/category-name
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you differentiate between `search/category-name` and `search/search-term`? By having a concept of what a category is and what a search term is, or perhaps by querying if the search term exists as a category. Mod_rewrite cannot do that. It just matches a pattern, and since you have 2 identical patterns for 2 different things you have to differentiate between them in your search file instead.

Besides that, an url like `example.com/search//something` might internally be represented by `example.com/search/something`, since it is still a path to a resource, not an arbitrary string of characters.

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/?$ search.php?search=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ search.php?search=$1&cat=$2 [L,QSA]
```

In search.php check if `$_GET['search']` is a category or a search term.

Alternatively change your urls to something like this: `search/search-term/category/category-name` and `search/category/category-name`. You can then be certain about what is in each of the path segments:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/category/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1&cat=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/category/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong regex. This `[^/]+` means at least one character.
You should change expression to `[^/]*`.

[Wiki: Standards of Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards)

Comment: thanks I tried this but neither search//category-name or search/category-name work